# How to get Bitmap From imageUri in Api level 30?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using getBitmap method in the older version but I can't find any alternative of getBitmap From Uri.

```
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

now I found another method from the android guide but still, this is not working.
I Don't how to perform this method in the worker thread.
Guide says that this method should run in a worker thread. can anyone help me with how to do this?

```
        try {
            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, imageUri));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I had created simple class to get bitmap from imageUri.
here it is.

```
public class BitmapResolver {


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Bitmap getBitmapLegacy(@NonNull ContentResolver contentResolver, @NonNull Uri fileUri){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, fileUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private static Bitmap getBitmapImageDecoder(@NonNull ContentResolver contentResolver, @NonNull Uri fileUri){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, fileUri));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmap(@NonNull ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri fileUri){
        if (fileUri == null){
            return null;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
            return getBitmapImageDecoder(contentResolver, fileUri);
        } else{
            return getBitmapLegacy(contentResolver, fileUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media#getBitmap(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri))

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
> loading of images should be performed through ImageDecoder#createSource(ContentResolver, Uri), which offers modern features like PostProcessor.

So you have to make use of `ImageDecoder.createSource`, like this:

```java
Bitmap bitmap = null;
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver(); 
try {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri);
    } else {
        ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, imageUri);
        bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above should be thread-safe.

Comment: Doing the same as you assist. But Still Not working. Here i Have updated question.

Comment: "But Still Not working" What exactly is not working? What happens when you run the above?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. It's working now. Some other issue happened in code

Answer (score 4):

Here it For Kotlin Developers

```
fun getBitmap(contentResolver: ContentResolver, fileUri: Uri?): Bitmap? {
    return try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, fileUri!!))
        } else {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, fileUri)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception){
        null
    }
}
```